# PHP Replace specific values inside formula

Tags: php

I have a formula where some of the data needs to be replaced by MYSQLI query results.

The formula can look like:

```
100+400-600-700
```

The numbers in the formula will match a specific table line in the DB and output correct value, for example:

```
121000+1000-8000-2000
```

I've tried to extract all the special characters from the original string in order to get the correct DB result via MYSQLI using formula:

```
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $rf, $matches);

foreach ($matches as $key1 => $value) {

                    //Declare summarization of TOT rows
                    $TOT = 0;
                    foreach ($value as $single) {

                    $querymatch = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT rowMainAccount FROM reportTable_rowDefinitions WHERE rowCode = '$single' AND reportID = $rowDefinition");
                    $arraymatch = mysqli_fetch_array($querymatch);
                    $TOTaccount = $arraymatch['rowMainAccount'];

                        //Fetch values from FinancialTransactions
                        //Fetch values

                                    $queryTOT = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT SUM(debit) AS debitTOT, SUM(credit) AS creditTOT FROM FinancialTransactions WHERE mainAccount = $TOTaccount AND entity = $org AND date BETWEEN '$newStartDate' AND '$newEndDate'");
                                    $arrayTOT = mysqli_fetch_array($queryTOT);
                                    $TOTcred += $arrayTOT['creditTOT'];
                                    $TOTdeb += $arrayTOT['debitTOT'];


                    }
                    $TOT += $TOTdeb - $TOTcred;

                }
                echo $TOT; //Returns values
```

This will only replace the numbers in the original string giving result as

```
121000100080002000
```

from foreach loop.

How can I put the returned values from DB into the original formula to acieve the correct output as

```
121000+1000-8000-2000
```

?

Comment: If you could share some more code and data e.g. what is the original formula, how does it match a row in the database, what is the data from the database and how that should be mapped to the desired result it would be much easier to answer...

Comment: lets see what you have tried to do. That will be a good startup point

Comment: will you always have a `+` and 3 `-`  in the string? and against each number there is a code in db?

Comment: Maybe `select column, replace(replace(column, '+, ''), '-', '') from ..`? not really clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Added code to reflect how I retrieve the values from MYSQLI database. How can I populate the '+' and '-' signs at correct place in the result string based on the original formula?

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_replace_callback` and in the callback you can get the appropriate value and `return` it to place it in the original string.

Comment: Could you please share an example of how you would use this expression to get the desired result above?